# Creating an R package for windows

Tags: windows, r, package

I created an R package on Linux (and it is working on Linux), but I can't make the same package work on Windows.

What I tried to do (maybe it was a bit foolish) was to convert the tar.gz into a Zip file and to install it from the R GUI.

However, when I load the package library("myPackage") then I get the following message:

```
  Error in library("myPackage") :
     there is no package called 'myPackage'
```

Should I try to build the package directly from Windows with the R tools?

Answer (score 8, accepted):

To build an R package on Windows, download the tools at
 
      http://cran.r-project.org/bin/windows/Rtools/
 
and follow the instructions at
 
      http://robjhyndman.com/researchtips/building-r-packages-for-windows/

Comment: Thanks, you article is just GREAT. It explains everything very smoothly. Thanks for the link!

Answer (score 3):

Yes, you should make it directly on Windows. See the [R Extensions manual](http://cran.r-project.org/doc/manuals/R-exts.html) and a number of tutorials on the web.