# Installing packages from RProfile.site file

Tags: r, rprofile

I asked this question earlier, but am still unable to get it working. I am trying to install custom packages upon starting R. A lot of the code that is written by us right now is available for editing to the users. To try and protect the code, I am packaging the production level code and having the users install it on their machine during start up.

However, when I try to install packages in RProfile.site file, the program goes into a loop and R is constantly launched over and over. I noticed that a lock file for the package is created along with the package in the library folder within R.

Here is the code I have added to the site file:

```
if(length(grep("customPackage", installed.packages()[,1]))==0) { 
        install.packages("customPackage", repos=NULL, type="source") 
}
```

When I try to run this code after starting R (without changing the site file), it installs the package perfectly fine and moves on. However, when I try to do it through the RProfile file, that's when it creates the problems.

Last time I tried resolving this issue ([https://stackoverflow.com/questions/10610067/installing-packages-upon-starting-r-session](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/10610067/...)), I thought Justin's suggestion of using the if statement check for packages would fix the problem. But this only seems to solve the problem for packages I install from CRAN and not custom packages.

Any help on this matter would be greatly appreciated!

Comment: Windows 7 - 64 bit. My RProfile file is in C:\Program Files\R\R-2.15.0\etc\Rprofile.site

Comment: Please don't crosspost: https://stat.ethz.ch/pipermail/r-help/2012-July/318647.html

Comment: Sorry for the crosspost. Will not do it again in the future.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

I don't understand why you'd want to do this.  Just have them point their `.libPaths` to the same place.  i.e. instead of `install.packages(...)`, just add a line in Rprofile.site that says

```
.libPaths('/path/to/common/libraries')
require("commonPackage")
```

Another thing that you might be able to do is make a `system` call.  I don't know much about installing packages under Windows, but on Unix-alike, instead of using `install.packages` you could do something like this:

```
system("R --vanilla CMD INSTALL customPackage")
```

Among other things, the `--vanilla` flag causes R to be started without using the Rprofile.site file (Your problem is that the Rprofile.site file is being read when R starts,  but the Rprofile.site file tells R to install a package which requires starting R, which in turns reads your Rprofile.site file... etc.).  Presumably, `R --no-site-file INSTALL customPackage` would also work.

**Edit**

After consulting [this SO answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/2971434/967840), it looks like you could do something like this on Windows (assuming you have installed [Rtools](http://cran.us.r-project.org/bin/windows/Rtools/)), although I haven't tested it.

```
system("Rcmd --vanilla INSTALL customPackage")
```

Comment: I am trying to install these packages on each user's computer, hence there isn't a common place I can install these packages (unless it's on the network drive where I am getting the following error:
ERROR: loading failed for 'i386', 'x64'. This happened when I added the .libPaths line and tried installing a package after that.)

Comment: The `.libPaths` suggestion was to install packages on a network drive instead of on the users' computers.  i.e. Whenever you want to update the version of a package that everyone is using, use the `lib` argument of `install.packages` from some non-user computer.  Then, when a user starts a new R session, it will pick up the new version of the package.  The suggestion for installing the package on each user's computer every time they start R (which is not advisable) was to use `system` and `Rcmd --vanilla INSTALL`.  Did you try that?

Comment: Well, so I tried both, but I tried it with the .libPaths line in the RProfile.site file. Installing directly onto the network drive always caused me to get the ERROR: loading failed for 'i386', 'x64' error. The only workaround I can think of right now is to install the custom packages and update them on my machine and then copy them over to the network drive. I can have everyone's RProfile.site file just point to the network drive and I can maintain the installation on my end. It's not ideal, but it seems to work with the one install I have tried so far.

Comment: When you install the packages on your machine, use the `lib` argument with the path to your network drive so that they are installed on the network drive.  Then in the users' Rprofile, set `.libPaths` to that same directory

Comment: What's wrong with using the `system` call (aside from the fact that if the answer is `system` you should probably rethink the question)?

Comment: So that's what I had tried earlier (using the lib argument with the path to the network drive) and installing the package on the network from my machine. That was when I got the error I mentioned above. I believe it might be because I do not have access to the C drive on the network drive. I tried using the system call, but it does not recognize vanilla as a command. Without using vanilla, I was getting the same error trying to install the package on the network.

Comment: Try `system("R --vanilla CMD INSTALL customPackage")` instead of `Rcmd`

Comment: Still get the same error. It goes through the install of the package, and then at the end it says: 

Error: loading failed
Execution halted
ERROR: loading failed for 'i386', 'x64'

Comment: Can you install a package from the command line using `R --vanilla CMD INSTALL`?  You have to be able to do that before wrapping a `system` call around it inside R will be of any use.

Comment: That's what I tried doing. That's where I am getting the error.

Comment: Ha. Then read up on how to install packages under Windows. See the links in my answer.

Comment: Thanks for all the help man. I'll look through the links some more and see if I can find a more elegant solution.

Answer (score 2):

As GSee said, the problem is that `install.packages` runs `R CMD INSTALL`, which starts a new R process that reads the Rprofile.site file, resulting in a loop. Two ways to break the evil loop:

1. Check that R is running interactively:

   ```
   if (interactive() && 
       length(grep("customPackage", installed.packages()[,1]))==0) { 
     install.packages("customPackage", repos=NULL, type="source") 
   }
   ```

   `interactive()` is FALSE when `R CMD` is running, so this breaks the loop.
2. Set the `R_PROFILE` environment variable to an empty or invalid value, so the R session in `R CMD` won't run yours. [Initialization at Start of an R Session](https://stat.ethz.ch/R-manual/R-devel/library/base/html/Startup.html) says:

   > If you want ‘~/.Renviron’ or ‘~/.Rprofile’ to be ignored by child R processes (such as those run by R CMD check and R CMD build), set the appropriate environment variable R_ENVIRON_USER or R_PROFILE_USER to (if possible, which it is not on Windows) "" or to the name of a non-existent file.

   Adapting that for Rprofile.site, you can set `R_PROFILE` to an empty or nonexistent file, before you call `install.packages`. For example:

   ```
   if (length(grep("customPackage", installed.packages()[,1]))==0) { 
     Sys.setenv(R_PROFILE = "/dev/null")
     install.packages("customPackage", repos=NULL, type="source") 
     Sys.unsetenv("R_PROFILE")
   }
   ```

   Then when R restarts to install packages, it reads an empty Rprofile.site file, so again you break the loop .

   If the call to `install.packages` is in .Rprofile, you can set `R_PROFILE_USER` in the same way.

The first method is simpler, and doesn't require you to worry about maybe overwriting an existing value of `R_PROFILE`.

Comment: I had a call to `system("stty size", intern = T)` (then I was setting `options(width=x)` with `x` being the second number returned, to fit R output to terminal size) in my .Rprofile and it was crashing every time I tried to install a package, with a cryptic error.
Took me some time to understand that my .Rprofile was called for each package I installed. `if(interactive())` was the best way to go. Thanks!

Comment: `interactive()` did not work for me, it was still looping. `R --vanilla CMD INSTALL` did not work, either. Resetting `R_PROFILE_USER` did the trick!

Answer (score 0):

You can use the function below to install package(s) without reloading `.Rprofile`:

```
surround <- function(x, with) {
  paste0(with, x, with)
}

peq <- function(x, y) paste(x, y, sep = " = ")

install.packages.vanilla <- function(pkgs, ...){

  arguments <- as.list(match.call())[-1]

  if(!"repos" %in% names(arguments)){
    arguments$repos <- getOption("repos")
  }
  names_args <- names(arguments)

  installArgs <- purrr::map_chr(seq_along(arguments),
                                function(i){
                                  value <- arguments[[i]]
                                  peq(names_args[i], ifelse(length(value)<2, deparse(value), as.character(list(value))))
                                })
  installArgs <- stringr::str_replace_all(installArgs, "\"", "'")
  installCmd <- paste0("utils::install.packages(",
                       paste(installArgs, collapse = ", "),
                       ")")
  fullCmd <- paste(
    surround(file.path(R.home("bin"), "R"), with = "\""),
    "--vanilla",
    "--slave",
    "-e",
    surround(installCmd, with = "\"")
  )

  system(fullCmd)
  return(invisible())
}
```