# Strange behaviour when computing svd on a covariance matrix: different results between Microsoft R and vanilla R

Tags: r, svd, microsoft-r

I was doing some principal component analysis on my macbook running Microsoft R 3.3.0 when I got some strange results. Double checking with a colleague, I've realised that the output of the SVD function was different from what I may get by using vanilla R.

This is the reproducible result, please load the file (~78 Mb) [here](https://dl.dropboxusercontent.com/u/1249990/Cx.rda)

With Microsoft R 3.3.0 (x86_64-apple-darwin14.5.0) I get:

```
>> sv <- svd(Cx)
>> print(sv$d[1:10])

 [1] 122.73664 104.45759  90.52001  87.21890  81.28256  74.33418      73.29427  66.26472  63.51379
[10]  55.20763
```

Instead on a vanilla R (both with R 3.3 and R 3.3.1 on two different linux machines):

```
>> sv <- svd(Cx)
>> print(sv$d[1:10])

 [1] 122.73664  34.67177  18.50610  14.04483   8.35690   6.80784   6.14566
 [8]   3.91788   3.76016   2.66381
```

This is not happening with all the data, if I create some random matrix and I apply svd on that, I get the same results. So, it looks like a sort of numerical instability, isn't it?

UPDATE: I've tried to compute the SVD on the same matrix (`Cx`) on the same machine (macbook) with the same version of R by using the `svd` package and finally I get the "right" numbers. Then it seems due to the svd implementation used by Microsoft R Open.

UPDATE: The behaviour happens also on MRO 3.3.1

Comment: With MRS 3.2.2 on Windows, I get a result matching vanilla R. Maybe double-check that you're using the same data on both machines.

Comment: use a seed, and then make sure you're using the same seed on both machines to help verify

Comment: @HongOoi I've checked, it's the same data. Maybe it's something related to the mac libraries...

Comment: I see that Microsoft R on MAC use the Apple Accelerate framework for BLAS, I'd like to use 1 thread instead of the 4 I'm actually using but I don't know how to set it.

Comment: Could you post your update as an answer ... ?

Comment: @BenBolker Well, it seems still a partial answer, I'll post something more complete asap.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

It seems this is a sort of bug, as confirmed [in the Github of microsoft-r-open](https://github.com/Microsoft/microsoft-r-open/issues/8#issuecomment-254345602). 
They say this behaviour is under investigation and it's related with the Accelerate library in MacOs.

Answer (score 1):

The typical example forms an ill-conditioned matrix. There are some SV closest to zero making the SVD decomposition numerical sensitive to different implementations of the SVD, which is probably what you are seen

Comment: Probably, but the difference is huge, you get different principal components on two different machines...